# JPA without Facade interfaces or DAO interfaces

Tags: java, jpa, interface, ejb-3.0, facade

I am looking this example JPA implementation using Jdeveloper.
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/bleonard/archive/2013/08/30/exposing-jpa-entities-restful-web-services-oracle-cloud

Wondering why interface DAO classes or Facade interfaces are not used. What is the real reason for interface classes and then implementation classes which implements interfaces.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: It's a simple tutorial. You'd have to ask the author (to which he would probably answer "it's a simple tutorial").

Comment: @Kayaman I agree, but wondering what is the real usages of interfaces for facade or dao?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159813/do-i-need-to-use-an-interface-when-only-one-class-will-ever-implement-it